# Pointer to a bidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Declaring an array

```
char a[10][20] = {...}
```

I can't find the right way to create a pointer `x` so that `a[1][3]`, for example, is `x[1][3]`.

I tried:

```
// try 1
char * x; x = &a[0][0];
// try 2
char * x; x = a;
// try 3
char ** x; x = a;
// try 4
char ** x; x = &a[0][0];
```

How do I work this out?

Comment: `char(*x)[20] = a;` A reference is better because it doesn't lose any size information: `char(&x)[10][20] = a;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say `char (*p)[20] = a;`, which makes `p` into a pointer to an array of 20 chars. This means that `++p` leaps to the next slice of 20, and you have 10 of those slices (each denoted by the expression `p[i]`, where 0 ≤ *i* < 10.

Comment: How can I return `p` from a function? How do I set the type of the function that returns p?

Comment: @Jeff; `typedef char (*my_array_pointer_type)[20]; my_array_pointer_type forExample() {}` But make sure you [don't forget your bible in the hotel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes... mmm, ok and where do I place it if the function name is `forExample() {}`?

Comment: @JeffPigarelli: Don't use raw arrays or raw pointers in C++ at all. At all. Take a look at the standard library and use an appropriate container.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `a` is of type `char (*)[20]`, i.e., the type pointer to an array 20 of `char`.

You can declare an object `x` of this type this way:

```
char a[10][20] = { ... };
char (*x)[20] = a;

x[3][14] = 42;  // you can then access x elements like with a
```

Comment: Not quite; the type of `a` is `char[10][20]`, which is convertible to `char (*)[20]` where necessary.

Comment: @MikeSeymour the type of `a` is `char[10][20]`, the type of the value of `a` is `char (*)[20]`.

Comment: I don't know what you think you mean by "the type of the value of `a`", but it's still an array. Like all arrays, it can be converted to a pointer when necessary, but it still has the type of an array.

Comment: How can I return `p` from a function? How do I set the type of the function that returns `p`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular pointer to a bidimensional array this way

```
int arr[10][20];
int* p = (int*) arr; or p = &arr[0][0];
//the mean to set or get value of the member [i][j]
*(p+20*i +j) = 777;
int a = *(p+20*i+j);
```